# How to keep if-statement with curly brackets as one line

Tags: prettier

In our Node JS application, prettier reformats this:

```js
if (a == 4) { return 34; }
if (b == 4) { return 36; }
```

into this:

```js
if (a == 4) {
  return 34;
}
if (b == 4) {
  return 36;
}
```

Which makes sense as a default behavior, however we have a strong preference for one liners especially when the if statement is short. Currently our .prettierrc is:

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "semi": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 9999
}
```

Is there anyway to modify this file to keep short if-statements on one line? We could remove the curly braces but then `eslist` is unhappy and we do not want to change the `eslist` `curly` rule as we do prefer keeping the `{` `}` brackets.

Comment: Dumb question from me: "What should happen when a!=4 and b!=4 ?   (I am thinking you could replace both if's with: `return a==4?34:b==4?36:null;` )

Comment: The code example above is just to showcase the braces issue. Although, to answer your question (because we do use this pattern), there would be additional code that would run below if both `a != 4` and `b != 4`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think prettier supports that. After all, prettier is an `opinionated` formatter.

Copied from the docs :

> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.

Comment: I don't think it does either, but I'm not 100% certain